# Reuse XAML style for Rectangles in WPF Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I'm currently working on a .NET 4.7.1 application. I need to create a Canvas in WPF, on the canvas are some rectangles placed.
The rectangles do have a certain style. I don't want to rewrite the style each time.

I'm looking for a way to reuse the style in respect of my canvas elements, similar to CSS in HTML.

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="2" ClipToBounds="True" Background="Gainsboro">
    <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="3" Canvas.Left="25" Canvas.Top="25" Width="200" Height="100">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightCoral"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightCoral"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Gainsboro"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gainsboro"/>
                <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <Rectangle Panel.ZIndex="2" Fill="LightCoral" Canvas.Left="450" Canvas.Top="50" Width="200" Height="100" />
</Canvas>
```

Do you know how to apply the Rectangle.Fill on all the rectangles?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: put the style in Canvas.Ressources

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By putting the style in the canvas.ressources like shown below all rectangles in your canvas will have the same gradient fill

```
<Canvas Height="200">
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,1" SpreadMethod="Repeat">
                        <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="LightCoral"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="LightCoral"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="Gainsboro"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Gainsboro"/>
                        <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.01" ScaleY="0.01"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Canvas.Resources>
    <Rectangle Height="50" Width="50"/>
    <Rectangle Canvas.Left="70" Height="50" Width="50"/>
</Canvas>
```

[image]